# BVP and uniqueness theorems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we consider the BVP $y'' + y = 0$, for  $0 \le x \le b$, $y(0) = 0$, and $y(b) = B$.

Then what are choices for $b$ and $B$ s.t. the BVP has:

-no solution?

-exactly 1 solution?

-infinitely many solutions?

I solved the DE above, and got $y(x) = A\cos(x) + B\sin(x)$, can someone verify this? I used inspection.

Thanks

Comment: Your inspection is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of $y''+y=0$ is $y(x)=C\cos(x)+D\sin(x)$, which you found by inspection. Now, $y(0)=0$ implies that $C\underbrace{\cos(0)}_{1}+D\underbrace{\sin(0)}_{0}=C=0$, so $y(x)=D\sin(x)$. Furthermore, since $y(b) = B$, we require that $D\sin(b)=B$. Obviously, if $\sin(b)=0$ and $B\neq0$, then there is no solution. On the other hand, if $\sin(b)=0$ and $B=0$, then there are infinitely many solutions for $D$ (any number will do). Finally, if $\sin(b)\neq0$, then $D=\frac{B}{\sin(b)}$, and the unique solution is given by $y(x)=B\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(b)}$.